# python sklearn.compose.columntransformer handling missing columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, data-processing

I am using [columntransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) for my machine learning data, When I use fit_transform I have a dataset containing the tag columns, but when I use transform for prediction I get an error, due to the missing tags columns (even when the transformer has no transformation regarding that column at all.)

> ````
> 'positional indexers are out-of-bounds'}```
> ````

Is there any whey to handle this more gracefully? e.g just not transforming the missing column that has no transformations over it to begin with? Alternatively, is it safe to just create a dummy column? How can I check what columns and columns order the transformer is expecting?

example case:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], columns=[0, 1, 2])
c = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("norm1", Normalizer(norm='l1'), [0, 1])], remainder="passthrough")
df1 = c.fit_transform(df)
df2 = df.drop(2, axis=1)
data = c.transform(df2)
```

gives

> raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds") IndexError:
>   positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: If you could provide a Minimal example your question would likely be more addressable. It would at least provide some data for discussion.

Comment: @FChm done adding example